# OutOfMemoryError - how to kill the JVM after the hprof created

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, sun, hprof

I want my java to exit when catching `OutOfMemoryError`, I'm using the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to dump `hprof` file. 
I can't use `kill -9 <pid>` because the JVM needs to be up while dumping the `hprof` file, is there any way to stop the JVM after the `hprof` file created?


To be clear I'm using Sun's JVM version 6.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Deployment+Considerations+-+Sun+JVMs) seems to imply that you *can* combine `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"`

Presumably, the heap dump is created before the "On..." command is run.  (It should be easy to throw together something to test this out.)

Comment: I combined these two JVM args, your assumption is not fully correct, The heap dump creation parallel to "On..." command, in my case the kill happened before dump is fully created, the death of the JVM in the middle of dump creation causing the `hprof` to be corrupted.

Comment: OK, so the Oracle page is misleading.  But you should still be able to work with that behavior to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @shaiis.com did this solution work? Do these 2 parameters work together correctly?